# Error when trying to add a 32bit driver to Server 2008 64bit

Tags: printing, network-printer

We have some network printers that Toshiba suplies generic drivers for on the CD. Now installing the 64bit edition works fine on the Server, but when I try to add a 32bit driver for those clients, the dialog tells me this.
[image]

I've tried the "32bit drivers on the CD" and the ones on Toshiba's site, neither of them work , however the 64 bit drivers on the site work and result in the same effect as the CD. Also note that trying to load directly on a client doesn't work either.

**Update**

The workstations accept the drivers, but the server still gives the error. Though I now have an alternative, I would really like to deploy with GPO.

Comment: How are you adding the driver? By running the setup.exe from the cd, or by adding additional drivers through the server properties?

Comment: The Printer properties on the Server.

Comment: So you're going Control Panel > Printers > Server Properties > Drivers Tab > Add... and it's throwing the error?

Comment: Yes, I'm in the print server snap in.

Comment: From a workstation where the drivers could be installed, login as admin, connect to the server and try and add your drivers.

Comment: Did you select x86 when you were adding the driver?  This isn't the issue that you'd typically see with a failed install of 32 bit drivers on a 64 bit server (those are usually problems with ntprint.inf) - this is just a "that driver isn't for the architecture that was picked".

Comment: @Zoredache Doesn't work, error about not finding a driver.

Comment: @shanemadden Yes, I made sure to select x86.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I'm gonna break the bad news for you. It sounds like there is no support for that printer on 2008R2. I had a similar issue in the past with 32 bit print drivers for XP on a 2008R2 print server, and the solution in the long run was to upgrade all the clients to Win7.

The fact that there's no Win7 driver for the printer makes me believe that there is no support for this printer on this platform, as 2008r2 and Win7 share the same code base.

Basically, it sounds like you're out of luck. If you're stuck, you might be able to run a virtual machine with 2003 somewhere and have your XP clients pointed there.